# multiplication of polynomial in C using list

Tags: c, polynomials

I'm using lists to implement the multiplication of polynomials.
My code is:

```
typedef struct node *node_ptr;
typedef struct node
{
    unsigned int power;
    int coeff;
    node_ptr next;
}POLY;
typedef node_ptr polynomial; 

void mult_polynomial(polynomial poly1, polynomial poly2, polynomial poly_mult)
{
    assert(!is_null(poly1) && !is_null(poly2) && is_null(poly_mult));
    node_ptr p1 = poly1->next;
    node_ptr p2;
    node_ptr p3;
    node_ptr tmp, cell;

    while (p1) {
        p2 = poly2->next;
        while (p2) {
            p3 = poly_mult;
            cell = p3->next;
            tmp = (node_ptr)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            tmp->power = p1->power + p2->power;
            tmp->coeff = p1->coeff * p2->coeff;
            tmp->next = NULL;
            if (!cell)
                p3->next = tmp;
            else { 
                if (cell->power == tmp->power) {
                    cell->coeff += tmp->coeff;
                    free(tmp);   
                } else if (cell->power < tmp->power) {
                    p3->next = tmp;
                    tmp->next = cell;
                } else if (cell->power > tmp->power) {
                    while (cell->power > tmp->power) {
                        if(!cell->next || cell->next->power < tmp->power) {
                            cell->next = tmp;
                            break; 
                        } else if (cell->next->power == tmp->power) {
                            cell->next->coeff += tmp->coeff;
                            break;
                        }
                        p3 = cell;
                        cell = p3->next;
                    }
                }
            }
            p2 = p2->next;
        }
        p1 = p1->next;
    }
}
```

But it seems too redundant; how to simplify it?

Comment: See [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers), to which the short answer is "No" — but see the question for the details.

Comment: You need to change the type of `poly_mult`, I think —if it is null on entry to the function, you have only changed the local copy in the function when it returns.  You either need to pass a `polynomial *` or return the `polynomial` (but then you don't need the third argument).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thk

Comment: YW: I hoped (in vain, it seems) that someone else would comment on it being a good idea to provide an MCVE ([MCVE]). You've provided a key function — but for us to test the code, we've got to write code to create and print polynomials (and maybe free), which is not hard, but it is a nuisance to have to write it. I think you're keeping your polynomial in a list with descending powers, for example, so we have to make sure we copy that. Also, if the code is running, then it's nominally more of a candidate for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but they'll probably want an MCVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take on a solution.  It is basically a complete rewrite — though the structure used is only renamed but structurally equivalent to what you had.

The function `add_term()` turns out to be crucial — it is a variant of part of what you had in `mult_polynomial()`, but it also lends itself to use in `add_polynomial()` and `sub_polynomial()` — one factor which indicates that it is a useful abstraction.  Note that `mult_polynomial()` itself is very simple and compact as a result — and neither `add_polynomial()` nor `sub_polynomial()` is any more complex.

I'm not completely happy with the code in `add_term()` (there are too many special cases), but I believe it does its job reasonably well.   You can end up with a polynomial with many terms that have 0 as the coefficient; the code does not remove such terms, though it could (should) be upgraded to do so.  The printing code accordingly has to skip such terms — and has a special case to deal with all terms zero (it prints `0`, of course).

Also, the design of `mult_polynomial()` in the question is inadequate.  If you have `void mult_polynomial(polynomial *p1, polynomial *p2, polynomial *p3)`, you can't get the new data in `p3` out of the function.  The options are to use `polynomial **p3` or to return the new polynomial — this code returns the new value.

And, as already mentioned in the comments, it is generally best not to used `typedef` for data pointers (function pointers are a different matter).  You can find out more at [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers).  I ended up with one structure for polynomials, which is the same as the structure for a term in a polynomial.  (The test code uses a pair of structures, a `term` and a `termlist`, to describe polynomials for testing purposes.  They make life easier.  There's a modest amount of test code.  The `add_polynomial()` and `sub_polynomial()` functions were completed inside 10 minutes, including fixing up the printing for `0` polynomials, which is a testament to the usefulness of the `add_term()` function.

The `print_polynomial()` function is important and useful.  It also has to deal with some fiddly special cases (negative coefficients, first coefficient negative, zero coefficients, power of one, and power of zero).  It should arguably be generalized to allow the variable name to be specified; it is hard-coded as `x`.  There might be some simpler functions trying to escape — one possibility is a `print_term()` function that could be used elsewhere as well as being called in `print_polynomial()`.  There'd be tricky communication to handle the fiddly special cases, of course.

An FYI: I define all functions (other than `main()`) as `static` unless there's a second source file that references them and a header file that declares them.  Clearly, some of these functions would become publicly accessible if the code was to be reused and would then be made `extern` (non-`static`) and declared in a header.  The details of the type would not be in the header; the `typedef struct polynomial polynomial;` would be there, but that's all that would be needed.  The definition would be hidden in the implementation file.  This would be an *opaque type*.  Some functions such as `add_term()` and `make_term()` would remain as `static` functions.

The code uses C99 designated initializers and compound literals.  It could be written using C89/C90 code, but it would be harder and/or messier.  Not necessarily very much harder, but…

Without further ado, here's the code (it's quite long):

```
/* SO 4313-7847 */
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "emalloc.h"

typedef struct polynomial polynomial;

struct polynomial
{
    unsigned int power;
    int          coeff;
    polynomial  *next;
};

static void print_polynomial(const char *tag, const polynomial *poly);

static polynomial *make_term(unsigned int power, int coeff, polynomial *next)
{
    polynomial *new_term = MALLOC(sizeof(*new_term));
    new_term->power = power;
    new_term->coeff = coeff;
    new_term->next  = next;
    return new_term;
}

static polynomial *add_term(polynomial *poly, unsigned int power, int coeff)
{
    if (coeff == 0)
        return poly;
    if (poly == NULL)
        return make_term(power, coeff, NULL);

    /* Find where this term goes */
    polynomial *term = poly;
    polynomial *prev = NULL;
    while (term != NULL && term->power > power)
    {
        prev = term;
        term = term->next;
    }

    if (term != NULL && term->power == power)
    {
        term->coeff += coeff;
        /* Eliminate zero terms here */
    }
    else
    {
        assert(term == NULL || term->power < power);
        polynomial *new_term = make_term(power, coeff, term);
        if (prev == NULL)
            poly = new_term;
        else
            prev->next = new_term;
    }
    return poly;
}

static polynomial *mult_polynomial(polynomial *poly1, polynomial *poly2)
{
    assert(poly1 != NULL && poly2 != NULL);
    polynomial *result = NULL;

    for (polynomial *p1 = poly1; p1 != NULL; p1 = p1->next)
    {
        for (polynomial *p2 = poly2; p2 != NULL; p2 = p2->next)
            result = add_term(result, p1->power + p2->power, p1->coeff * p2->coeff);
    }
    return result;
}

static polynomial *add_polynomial(polynomial *poly1, polynomial *poly2)
{
    assert(poly1 != NULL && poly2 != NULL);
    polynomial *result = NULL;

    for (polynomial *p1 = poly1; p1 != NULL; p1 = p1->next)
        result = add_term(result, p1->power, p1->coeff);
    for (polynomial *p2 = poly2; p2 != NULL; p2 = p2->next)
        result = add_term(result, p2->power, p2->coeff);
    return result;
}

static polynomial *sub_polynomial(polynomial *poly1, polynomial *poly2)
{
    assert(poly1 != NULL && poly2 != NULL);
    polynomial *result = NULL;

    for (polynomial *p1 = poly1; p1 != NULL; p1 = p1->next)
        result = add_term(result, p1->power, p1->coeff);
    for (polynomial *p2 = poly2; p2 != NULL; p2 = p2->next)
        result = add_term(result, p2->power, -p2->coeff);
    return result;
}

static void print_polynomial(const char *tag, const polynomial *poly)
{
    int printed = 0;
    printf("%s:", tag);
    char sign = ' ';
    while (poly != NULL)
    {
        int coeff = poly->coeff;
        if (coeff != 0)
        {
            if (sign != ' ' && coeff < 0)
            {
                sign = '-';
                coeff = -coeff;
            }
            if (poly->power == 0)
                printf(" %c %d", sign, coeff);
            else if (poly->power == 1)
                printf(" %c %dx", sign, coeff);
            else
                printf(" %c %dx^%u", sign, coeff, poly->power);
            printed++;
        }
        poly = poly->next;
        sign = '+';
    }
    if (printed == 0)
        printf("   0");
    putchar('\n');
    fflush(stdout);
}

static void free_polynomial(polynomial *poly)
{
    while (poly != NULL)
    {
        polynomial *next = poly->next;
        free(poly);
        poly = next;
    }
}

typedef struct term
{
    unsigned int power;
    int coeff;
} term;

typedef struct termlist
{
    int n_terms;
    term *terms;
} termlist;

static polynomial *make_polynomial(termlist *terms)
{
    polynomial *poly = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < terms->n_terms; i++)
    {
        printf("Term: %dx^%u\n", terms->terms[i].coeff, terms->terms[i].power);
        fflush(stdout);
        poly = add_term(poly, terms->terms[i].power, terms->terms[i].coeff);
    }
    return poly;
}

int main(void)
{
    termlist p1[] =
    {
        { .n_terms = 4, .terms = (term[]){ { 3, 2 }, { 2,  1 }, { 1,  4 }, { 0, -9 } } },
        { .n_terms = 3, .terms = (term[]){ { 2, 3 }, { 1, -4 }, { 0,  8 } } },
        { .n_terms = 3, .terms = (term[]){ { 1, 5 }, { 0,  3 }, { 2, -4 } } },
        { .n_terms = 2, .terms = (term[]){ { 4, 5 }, { 0, -5 } } },
        { .n_terms = 4, .terms = (term[]){ { 3, 2 }, { 2,  1 }, { 1,  4 }, { 2, -9 } } },
    };
    enum { NUM_POLYS = sizeof(p1) / sizeof(p1[0]) };
    polynomial *poly[NUM_POLYS] = { 0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_POLYS; i++)
    {
        poly[i] = make_polynomial(&p1[i]);
        print_polynomial("Building", poly[i]);
    }

    printf("Checking:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_POLYS; i++)
        print_polynomial("Next", poly[i]);
    putchar('\n');

    printf("Multiplying polynomials:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_POLYS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_POLYS; j++)
        {
            print_polynomial("Term 1", poly[i]);
            print_polynomial("Term 2", poly[j]);
            polynomial *prod = mult_polynomial(poly[i], poly[j]);
            print_polynomial("Product", prod);
            free_polynomial(prod);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    printf("Adding polynomials:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_POLYS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_POLYS; j++)
        {
            print_polynomial("Term 1", poly[i]);
            print_polynomial("Term 2", poly[j]);
            polynomial *sum = add_polynomial(poly[i], poly[j]);
            print_polynomial("Sum", sum);
            free_polynomial(sum);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    printf("Subtracting polynomials:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_POLYS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_POLYS; j++)
        {
            print_polynomial("Term 1", poly[i]);
            print_polynomial("Term 2", poly[j]);
            polynomial *diff = sub_polynomial(poly[i], poly[j]);
            print_polynomial("Difference", diff);
            free_polynomial(diff);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_POLYS; i++)
        free_polynomial(poly[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

And the output, broken into three sections so you can see the start of the multiplication, addition and subtraction sections of the tests:

```
Term: 2x^3
Term: 1x^2
Term: 4x^1
Term: -9x^0
Building:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Term: 3x^2
Term: -4x^1
Term: 8x^0
Building:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Term: 5x^1
Term: 3x^0
Term: -4x^2
Building:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Term: 5x^4
Term: -5x^0
Building:   5x^4 - 5
Term: 2x^3
Term: 1x^2
Term: 4x^1
Term: -9x^2
Building:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Checking:
Next:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Next:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Next:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Next:   5x^4 - 5
Next:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
```

Multiplication:

```
Multiplying polynomials:
Term 1:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Term 2:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Product:   4x^6 + 4x^5 + 17x^4 - 28x^3 - 2x^2 - 72x + 81
Term 1:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Term 2:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Product:   6x^5 - 5x^4 + 24x^3 - 35x^2 + 68x - 72
Term 1:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Term 2:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Product:   -8x^5 + 6x^4 - 5x^3 + 59x^2 - 33x - 27
Term 1:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Term 2:   5x^4 - 5
Product:   10x^7 + 5x^6 + 20x^5 - 45x^4 - 10x^3 - 5x^2 - 20x + 45
Term 1:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Term 2:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Product:   4x^6 - 14x^5 + 8x^4 - 46x^3 + 88x^2 - 36x

Term 1:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Term 2:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Product:   6x^5 - 5x^4 + 24x^3 - 35x^2 + 68x - 72
Term 1:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Term 2:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Product:   9x^4 - 24x^3 + 64x^2 - 64x + 64
Term 1:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Term 2:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Product:   -12x^4 + 31x^3 - 43x^2 + 28x + 24
Term 1:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Term 2:   5x^4 - 5
Product:   15x^6 - 20x^5 + 40x^4 - 15x^2 + 20x - 40
Term 1:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Term 2:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Product:   6x^5 - 32x^4 + 60x^3 - 80x^2 + 32x

Term 1:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Term 2:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Product:   -8x^5 + 6x^4 - 5x^3 + 59x^2 - 33x - 27
Term 1:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Term 2:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Product:   -12x^4 + 31x^3 - 43x^2 + 28x + 24
Term 1:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Term 2:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Product:   16x^4 - 40x^3 + 1x^2 + 30x + 9
Term 1:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Term 2:   5x^4 - 5
Product:   -20x^6 + 25x^5 + 15x^4 + 20x^2 - 25x - 15
Term 1:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Term 2:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Product:   -8x^5 + 42x^4 - 50x^3 - 4x^2 + 12x

Term 1:   5x^4 - 5
Term 2:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Product:   10x^7 + 5x^6 + 20x^5 - 45x^4 - 10x^3 - 5x^2 - 20x + 45
Term 1:   5x^4 - 5
Term 2:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Product:   15x^6 - 20x^5 + 40x^4 - 15x^2 + 20x - 40
Term 1:   5x^4 - 5
Term 2:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Product:   -20x^6 + 25x^5 + 15x^4 + 20x^2 - 25x - 15
Term 1:   5x^4 - 5
Term 2:   5x^4 - 5
Product:   25x^8 - 50x^4 + 25
Term 1:   5x^4 - 5
Term 2:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Product:   10x^7 - 40x^6 + 20x^5 - 10x^3 + 40x^2 - 20x

Term 1:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Term 2:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Product:   4x^6 - 14x^5 + 8x^4 - 46x^3 + 88x^2 - 36x
Term 1:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Term 2:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Product:   6x^5 - 32x^4 + 60x^3 - 80x^2 + 32x
Term 1:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Term 2:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Product:   -8x^5 + 42x^4 - 50x^3 - 4x^2 + 12x
Term 1:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Term 2:   5x^4 - 5
Product:   10x^7 - 40x^6 + 20x^5 - 10x^3 + 40x^2 - 20x
Term 1:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Term 2:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Product:   4x^6 - 32x^5 + 80x^4 - 64x^3 + 16x^2
```

Addition:

```
Adding polynomials:
Term 1:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Term 2:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Sum:   4x^3 + 2x^2 + 8x - 18
Term 1:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Term 2:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Sum:   2x^3 + 4x^2 - 1
Term 1:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Term 2:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Sum:   2x^3 - 3x^2 + 9x - 6
Term 1:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Term 2:   5x^4 - 5
Sum:   5x^4 + 2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 14
Term 1:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Term 2:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Sum:   4x^3 - 7x^2 + 8x - 9

Term 1:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Term 2:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Sum:   2x^3 + 4x^2 - 1
Term 1:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Term 2:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Sum:   6x^2 - 8x + 16
Term 1:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Term 2:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Sum:   -1x^2 + 1x + 11
Term 1:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Term 2:   5x^4 - 5
Sum:   5x^4 + 3x^2 - 4x + 3
Term 1:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Term 2:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Sum:   2x^3 - 5x^2 + 8

Term 1:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Term 2:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Sum:   2x^3 - 3x^2 + 9x - 6
Term 1:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Term 2:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Sum:   -1x^2 + 1x + 11
Term 1:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Term 2:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Sum:   -8x^2 + 10x + 6
Term 1:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Term 2:   5x^4 - 5
Sum:   5x^4 - 4x^2 + 5x - 2
Term 1:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Term 2:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Sum:   2x^3 - 12x^2 + 9x + 3

Term 1:   5x^4 - 5
Term 2:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Sum:   5x^4 + 2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 14
Term 1:   5x^4 - 5
Term 2:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Sum:   5x^4 + 3x^2 - 4x + 3
Term 1:   5x^4 - 5
Term 2:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Sum:   5x^4 - 4x^2 + 5x - 2
Term 1:   5x^4 - 5
Term 2:   5x^4 - 5
Sum:   10x^4 - 10
Term 1:   5x^4 - 5
Term 2:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Sum:   5x^4 + 2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x - 5

Term 1:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Term 2:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Sum:   4x^3 - 7x^2 + 8x - 9
Term 1:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Term 2:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Sum:   2x^3 - 5x^2 + 8
Term 1:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Term 2:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Sum:   2x^3 - 12x^2 + 9x + 3
Term 1:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Term 2:   5x^4 - 5
Sum:   5x^4 + 2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x - 5
Term 1:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Term 2:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Sum:   4x^3 - 16x^2 + 8x
```

Subtraction:

```
Subtracting polynomials:
Term 1:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Term 2:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Difference:   0
Term 1:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Term 2:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Difference:   2x^3 - 2x^2 + 8x - 17
Term 1:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Term 2:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Difference:   2x^3 + 5x^2 - 1x - 12
Term 1:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Term 2:   5x^4 - 5
Difference:   -5x^4 + 2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 4
Term 1:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Term 2:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Difference: + 9x^2 - 9

Term 1:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Term 2:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Difference:   -2x^3 + 2x^2 - 8x + 17
Term 1:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Term 2:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Difference:   0
Term 1:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Term 2:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Difference:   7x^2 - 9x + 5
Term 1:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Term 2:   5x^4 - 5
Difference:   -5x^4 + 3x^2 - 4x + 13
Term 1:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Term 2:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Difference:   -2x^3 + 11x^2 - 8x + 8

Term 1:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Term 2:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Difference:   -2x^3 - 5x^2 + 1x + 12
Term 1:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Term 2:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Difference:   -7x^2 + 9x - 5
Term 1:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Term 2:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Difference:   0
Term 1:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Term 2:   5x^4 - 5
Difference:   -5x^4 - 4x^2 + 5x + 8
Term 1:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Term 2:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Difference:   -2x^3 + 4x^2 + 1x + 3

Term 1:   5x^4 - 5
Term 2:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Difference:   5x^4 - 2x^3 - 1x^2 - 4x + 4
Term 1:   5x^4 - 5
Term 2:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Difference:   5x^4 - 3x^2 + 4x - 13
Term 1:   5x^4 - 5
Term 2:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Difference:   5x^4 + 4x^2 - 5x - 8
Term 1:   5x^4 - 5
Term 2:   5x^4 - 5
Difference:   0
Term 1:   5x^4 - 5
Term 2:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Difference:   5x^4 - 2x^3 + 8x^2 - 4x - 5

Term 1:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Term 2:   2x^3 + 1x^2 + 4x - 9
Difference: - 9x^2 + 9
Term 1:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Term 2:   3x^2 - 4x + 8
Difference:   2x^3 - 11x^2 + 8x - 8
Term 1:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Term 2:   -4x^2 + 5x + 3
Difference:   2x^3 - 4x^2 - 1x - 3
Term 1:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Term 2:   5x^4 - 5
Difference:   -5x^4 + 2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x + 5
Term 1:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Term 2:   2x^3 - 8x^2 + 4x
Difference:   0
```